# Why is the $J$-homomorphism an isomorphism for $n=1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cobordism, stable-homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I am trying to proove that $\pi_{n+1}(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ using the Pontryagin-Thom construction and the special case $n=1$ of the $J$-homomorphism
$$
J_1:\pi_1(SO(n))\rightarrow \pi_{n+1}(S^n).
$$ 
but I can't find any reference of this specific case of the $J$-homomorphism being an isomorphism.

Where can I find a proof?

Comment: You can check chapter 19 of Switzer's book Algebraic Topology, around page 480 in my version.